# Why am I getting a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined"?

Tags: discord, discord.js

So this was working earlier, but after adding my guildCache map in order to hold server specific variables, it stopped working. I'm not sure where the error occurs, so I will be sending all of my code until the error point. Basically, on my guildCreate event the bot would normally send an image and text to the server owner, but all of a sudden my working code is now broken. Any thoughts?

My intents are GUILDS, GUILD_MESSAGES, DIRECT_MESSAGES

```
// Require the necessary modules
const config = require('./Data/config.json');
const insulter = require('insult');
require('dotenv').config();
const { Client, Collection } = require('discord.js');
// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: 4609 }); // GUILDS, GUILD_MESSAGES, DIRECT_MESSAGES
const guildCache = new Collection(); //For saving independent server variables

// Functions
function getUserFromMention(mention) {
    if (!mention) return;
    if (mention.startsWith('<@') && mention.endsWith('>')) {
        mention = mention.slice(2, -1);
        if (mention.startsWith('!')) {
            mention = mention.slice(1);
        }
        return client.users.cache.get(mention);
    }
}


// --------------- BOT EVENTS -----------------
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log(`[Client] Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    client.user.setActivity('you cry.', { 
        type: 'WATCHING' 
    });
    // Map servers to cache for variables (also done on server join and leave)
    client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
        guildCache.set(guild.id, {
            bullyTarget: undefined,
            lastInsultGenerated: undefined
        });
    });
    console.log(guildCache);
    console.log('');
});;

// On join server
client.on('guildCreate', async (guild) => {
    console.log(`[Client]: Joined \"${guild.name}\"!`);
    guildCache.set(guild.id, {
        bullyTarget: undefined,
        lastInsultGenerated: undefined
    });
    console.log(guildCache);
    console.log('');

    await client.users.cache.get(guild.ownerId).send({
        content: 'You\'ll ***regret*** adding me.',
        files: [{
          attachment: 'src/Data/trollge.jpg',
          name: 'trollge.jpg'
        }]
      })
      .then(console.log('[Client]: Sent join message to server owner :D\n'))
      .catch(console.error);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the owner isn't in the bot's cache. You should use [`UserManager.fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch) (on `client.users`)

```js
(await client.users.fetch(guild.ownerId)).send({
        content: 'You\'ll ***regret*** adding me.',
        files: [{
          attachment: 'src/Data/trollge.jpg',
          name: 'trollge.jpg'
        }]
      })
```

You can use the [`Guild.fetchOwner()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchOwner) method to also access their [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) info (roles, nickname, etc.)

```js
const owner = await guild.fetchOwner()
owner.send({
        content: 'You\'ll ***regret*** adding me.',
        files: [{
          attachment: 'src/Data/trollge.jpg',
          name: 'trollge.jpg'
        }]
      })
```